# Sort top N and group 'others' in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the df

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {'001': [14],
       '002': [3],
       '003': [2],
       '004': [6],
       '005': [7],
       '006': [1],
       '007': [2]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic,orient='index')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = df.rename(columns = {'index':'id',0:'count'})
sorted = df.sort_values('count',ascending=False)
print(sorted)
```

which results in

```
    id  count
0  001     14
4  005      7
3  004      6
1  002      3
2  003      2
6  007      2
5  006      1
```

and I wanted to sort the top 3 by the count column, and group the rest as 'others'. I imagine I'd want to do something like `not_top3 = sorted[3:]`, but can't figure out how to rename the id as 'others' from there. Once that's done, I assume use `groupby` and `sum` to do the rest.

Expected output would be:

```
    id  count
0  001     14
1  005      7
2  004      6
3  other    8
```

where 'other' is the sum of the remaining ids.

Comment: Maybe `.loc`? `not_top3 = sorted.loc[3:, :]`

Comment: @Ch3steR - added expected output

Comment: @lut17 LGTM. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`df.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to add a row at the bottom.

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values("count", ascending=False)
out = sorted_df.iloc[:3]
out.append(
    {"id": "others", "count": sorted_df["count"].iloc[3:].sum()},
    ignore_index=True,
)

       id  count
0     001     14
1     005      7
2     004      6
3  others      8
```

Comment: I was just about to paste this exact solution, but you already answered. I had one more point that you might want to add, and that's regarding the bad practice of naming a column with a name that's already a df method. Anyhow, upvoted already, just recommending another helpful comment if you see fit.

Comment: @ShlomiF True. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new `id`, where values less than the top three are mapped as `others`, then aggregate to get the new dataframe:

```
(df
.assign(id = np.where(df['count'].isin(df['count'].nlargest(3)), 
                      df['id'], 
                      'other'))
.groupby('id', 
         as_index = False, 
         sort = False)
.sum()
 )

      id  count
0    001     14
1    005      7
2    004      6
3  other      8
```