# How to select top N of two groups and aggregate the rest of the second group into "Others" with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I had a datased that had product, price, category, and county. I used this code to count the number of products per category per county:

```
df_count = df.groupby(['County','Category']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

My dataframe now looks like this:

|  | County | Category | counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Blekinge | Accessories & watches | 35 |
| 1 | Blekinge | Audio & video | 101 |
| 2 | Blekinge | Bicycles | 78 |
| 3 | Blekinge | Boat parts & accessories | 65 |
| 4 | Blekinge | Boats | 143 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 657 | Östergötland | Snowmobile parts & accessories | 2 |
| 658 | Östergötland | Snowmobiles | 5 |
| 659 | Östergötland | Sports & leisure equipment | 335 |
| 660 | Östergötland | Tools | 102 |
| 661 | Östergötland | Trucks & construction | 66 |

662 rows × 3 columns

There are 21 counties and 32 categories. Counts are the number of products in a category. Not all categories are necessary in a county.

I'd like to have a new dataframe with the top N (e.g. 2) largest category of each county and aggregate the remainder into "Others". I want this for each county and it'd look like this:

| County | Category | counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blekinge | Boats | 143 |
| Blekinge | Audio & video | 101 |
| Blekinge | Others | 178 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Östergötland | Sports & leisure equipment | 335 |
| Östergötland | Tools | 102 |
| Östergötland | Others | 175 |

I've seen previous posts that did similar for arrays

[How to group "remaining" results beyond Top N into "Others" with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835746/how-to-group-remaining-results-beyond-top-n-into-others-with-pandas)

[Sort top N and group 'others' in pandas df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67142016/sort-top-n-and-group-others-in-pandas-df)

and tried this

```
# group by & sort descending
df_sorted=df_count.groupby(['County','Category']).sum().sort_values('counts', ascending=False).reset_index()

# rename rows other than top-n to 'Others'
x_sorted.groupby('County').loc[x_sorted.index >=3, 'Category'] = 'Others'
```

and this

```
df_count.sort_values(by=['counts'], ascending=False).groupby('County').head(2).sort_values(by=['County']).reset_index(drop=True)

#not_top2 = df.groupby('Version').sum().sort('Value', ascending=False).index[2:]
not_top2 = x.groupby(['County','Category']).sum().sort_values('counts', ascending=False).index[2:]

dfnew = x.replace(not_top2, 'Other')

dfnew.groupby(['County','Category']).sum()
```

but didn't succeed to get the desired output.

Any help or guidance is very much appreciated!

Comment: Kindly provide a small sample dataframe with expected output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the below sequence of steps to get to your final output, which I believe is fairly straightforward.

With the hope of making it easy to follow, I will add comments in the code and the output per line.

```
# Grab top 2 largest caterogies of each country
top_two = df.groupby('County').apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, 'counts')).reset_index(drop=True)  

>>> top_two
         County                    Category  counts
0      Blekinge                       Boats     143
1      Blekinge               Audio & video     101
2  Östergötland  Sports & leisure equipment     335
3  Östergötland                       Tools     102

# Create a dataframe with the rest of the information
df_others = df.append(df.merge(top_two,'inner')).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

>>> df_others
         County                        Category  counts
0      Blekinge           Accessories & watches      35
2      Blekinge                        Bicycles      78
3      Blekinge        Boat parts & accessories      65
5  Östergötland  Snowmobile parts & accessories       2
6  Östergötland                     Snowmobiles       5
9  Östergötland           Trucks & construction      66

# Groupby country and Sum and assign 'others' under Category in the df_others dataframe
df_others = df_others.groupby('County')['counts'].sum().reset_index()
df_others['Category'] = 'Others'

>>> df_others
         County  counts Category
0      Blekinge     178   Others
1  Östergötland      73   Others
```

---

Finally, `concat()` the two dataframes to get your final output:

```
res = pd.concat([top_two,df_others]).sort_values('County').reset_index(drop=True)
>>> res
         County                    Category  counts
0      Blekinge                       Boats     143
1      Blekinge               Audio & video     101
2      Blekinge                      Others     178
3  Östergötland  Sports & leisure equipment     335
4  Östergötland                       Tools     102
5  Östergötland                      Others      73
```

Please get back if there's something unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iloc` and `pd.concat`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['County', 'counts'], ascending=False)
result = (
    df.groupby('County').apply(
        lambda x: pd.concat(
            [x.iloc[:2],
             x.iloc[2:].groupby('County', as_index=False)
             .agg({'counts': sum})
             .assign(Category='Others')]))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
         County                    Category  counts
0      Blekinge                       Boats     143
1      Blekinge               Audio & video     101
2      Blekinge                      Others     178
3  Östergötland  Sports & leisure equipment     335
4  Östergötland                       Tools     102
5  Östergötland                      Others      73
```

Comment: This solution worked well. It gives the results with top_N sorted in descending order and Others at the last row in each county. Thank you.